# when I run the code "env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')" in stable_baselines3 zoo

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I wanna use the pretrained model in the zoo
but when I want to make a new environment like:env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
I

```
Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
Intel MKL WARNING: Support of Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) enabled only processors has been deprecated. Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library 2025.0 will require Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tcliang/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py", line 14, in <module>
    import Box2D
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Box2D'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tcliang/code/py/graduation/rl-baselines3-zoo/train_try.py", line 10, in <module>
    env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
  File "/Users/tcliang/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 581, in make
    env_creator = load(spec_.entry_point)
  File "/Users/tcliang/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py", line 61, in load
    mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
  File "/Users/tcliang/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/tcliang/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/box2d/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gym.envs.box2d.bipedal_walker import BipedalWalker, BipedalWalkerHardcore
  File "/Users/tcliang/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise DependencyNotInstalled("box2D is not installed, run `pip install gym[box2d]`")
gym.error.DependencyNotInstalled: box2D is not installed, run `pip install gym[box2d]`
```

solve the problem which in the stable-lines3